# Set default value for URL parameter in HTTP GET in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-get, url-parameters, restify

I am using node.js restify.

I have a HTTP GET request that looks like this;

`http://127.0.0.1//read_val?XXX=123&YYY=456&ZZZ=789`

In my handling function, to retrieve the URL parameters, the relevant code will be like this;

```
var api_get_func = function (app, url_path) {
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        var XXX= req.query.XXX;
        var YYY = req.query.YYY;
        var ZZZ = req.query.ZZZ;

        //SQL query ...
        return next();
    }

    app.get(url_path, respond);
}
```

Now, what if I have a HTTP GET function like this below

`http://127.0.0.1//read_val?XXX=123&YYY=456`

The `ZZZ` parameter is not provided in the URL. How do I modify the code such that `ZZZ` will use a default value of, say, `111`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If just want to check if something is provided, then you could just do:

```
var ZZZ = req.query.ZZZ || 111;
```

**But...** GET parameters are query *strings*, so we probably want to make sure it is a number.

```
if (!parseInt(req.query.ZZZ)) {
  req.query.ZZZ = 111;
}
```

Or if you want to get ternary with it:

```
req.query.ZZZ = parseInt(req.query.ZZZ) ? req.query.ZZZ : 111;
```

Do note that the other parameters are a string and that this default is being set as a number. So, you might want `'111'` as opposed to `111`. Also, you can `parseInt` all of your query strings or `toString` them all if they are all a number, just try to make sure they all remain the same expected type. Unless of course these are all strings of text, in which case ignore all this.

Comment: `''` is not truthy; the rest of this follows though

Answer (score 2):

```
var api_get_func = function (app, url_path) {
    function respond(req, res, next) {
        var XXX= req.query.XXX;
        var YYY = req.query.YYY;
        var ZZZ = req.query.ZZZ || <YOUR DEFAULT VALUE>;

        //SQL query ...
        return next();
    }`enter code here`

    app.get(url_path, respond);
}
```

Comment: looks awesomely simple. Is this solution applicable only to node.js restify?

Comment: It is a general JavaScript thing. It is similar to doing `if (req.query.ZZZ || 111)` as the truthy value is returned.

Comment: you can use this as well if this value can be 0 then you can use simple tertiary operator(?:) as like

Comment: req.query.ZZZ === ' undefined'  ?  'default '  :   req.query.ZZZ

Comment: @Atul Agrawal, your answer is good but I think Kevin Reilly's is better. Sorry, I can only mark one answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In one line, the best way is this:

```
let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit || 0);
let page = parseInt(req.query.pagina || 1);
let offset = page * limit
```

Because you put a default value then you parse the content.

> req.query.limit || 0

This line check if the content was sent, if not, put 0 as default value

Comment: Beware that parseInt might return NaN values if the req.query.limit is "abc" as example.